# Using fgets() in file parsing

Tags: c, string, file, parsing, file-io

I have a file which contains several lines.

I am tokenizing the file, and if the token contains contains `.word`, I would like to store the rest of the line in c-string.

So if:
`array: .word 0:10`
I would like to store 0:10 in a c-string.

I am doing the following:

```
if (strstr(token, ".word")) {
    char data_line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH + 1];
    int word_ret = fgets(data_line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, fptr);
    printf(".word is %s\n", data_line);
}
```

The problem with this is that `fgets()` grabs the next line. How would I grab the remainder of the current line? Is that possible?

Thank you,

Comment: Use one of the `str*` functions. `strstr` returns a pointer to the occurrence of `".word"` in `token`, so you take that pointer, skip past the `".word"` part, and look for what you want there.

Comment: Wow, exact same solution as me :)

Comment: I'm afraid we would need to see how you've read in your _current_ line in order to assign `token`. The input is already consumed by that point and how you get to it depends upon how you saved it. Incidentally, tokenizing inputs is exactly what [`flex`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_lexical_analyser) was designed to do -- when combined with [`bison`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison), the end result can be very powerful.

Comment: That's way over kill for something so simple.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointer to a string - C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869578/pointer-to-a-string-c)

Answer (score 3):

[strstr()](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strstr/) returns a pointer to where the first character of ":word" is found.

This means that if you add the length of ":word" (5 characters) to that, you will get a pointer to the characters after ":word", which is the string you want.

```
char *x = strstr(token, ".word");
char *string_wanted = x + 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is obvious that you need to use fgets only once for every line you parse and then work with a buffer where the line is stored.

Next having a whole line you have several choices: if the string format is fixed (something like " .word") then you may use the result of "strstr" function to locate the start of ".word", advance 6 characters (including space) from it and print the required word from the found position.

Another option is more complex but in fact is a liitle bit better. It is using "strtok" function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have already read the input into a buffer, which I'm assuming is *token*, and from there you just copy from the return value of strstr + the length of ".word" to the end of the buffer. This is what I'd do:

```
char *location = strstr(token, ".word");
if (location != NULL) {
   char data_line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
   strncpy(data_line, location + 5, MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
   printf(".word is %s\n", data_line);
}
```

You could add 5 or 6 to the pointer *location* (depending on whether or not there's going to be a space after ".word") to get the rest of the line.

Also note that the size parameter in strncpy and fgets includes space for the terminating NUL character.