# Pointer to a string - C

Tags: c, string, parsing

I am parsing a text file, and when I come across the word `.word`, I want to grab the rest of the line. Here is what I have so far:

```
char *word_ptr;

if (strstr(token, ":")){
    // Some code

}

else if ((word_ptr = strstr(token, ".word"))) {
    char *string_wanted = word_ptr + 6;
    printf("Rest: '%s'\n", string_wanted);
}
```

`string_wanted` is not printing correctly. Is my usage of word_ptr correct when assigning it in the `else-if` statement? `string_wanted` is printing out nothing. When I add a 7 instead of a 6, it prints out 'ize'. I had the word size in my text file but now I removed it, I deleted the file and re-created it and done a clean build and the word 'ize' still shows up!! It does not exist in the file at all anymore so where did it come from?? I am really frustrated the word 'size' does not exist anymore in the file.

Here is what the file looked (when I had the word 'ize'):

```
array: .word 0:10
array_size: .word 10
```

Now I just removed the second line, so it is:
`array: .word 0:10`

Why isn't word_ptr printing out 0:10 when I add a 6 to it? I am pretty sure that word_ptr points to .word because when I print it, it prints .word. When tokenizing the line, `array:` is being tokenized so I know that it is getting there.

Any suggestions?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you try testing for a NULL on strstr?

Comment: Why would I test for that? Doesn't the block of code only execute if it wasn't null?

Comment: that is true, the only problem with this code is that it never gets to the else if (with the test case you provided), When I fixed that on my program everything worked as it should, please post full code up, the code you have posted has no problems.

Comment: A very similar (almost identical) question was asked about a day ago: [Using fgets() in file parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857202/using-fgets-in-file-parsing/7857239). Also, if this is homework tag it as such.

Comment: The 'homework' assumption accusation again..

Comment: I really think you need to edit your question to remove the if/else red herring and to show us what `token` contains coming into the block of code that is relevant. Without knowing the content of `token`, it's hard to tell you exactly what's going to happen.

Comment: I will.. please hold for the edit.

Comment: I have provided another answer that I hope explains to you why it is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're running around in circles a bit here. I think I see where your confusion is now, so I'll try to lay it out. Your tokenizer is taking a string and breaking it up into tokens. Each of these tokens is a separate string by itself. You don't specify what characters you are tokenizing on, so I'll just assume the space character.

In this case the string:

> array: .word 0:10

becomes three new strings:

> "array:"
>
> ".word"
>
> "0:10"

If you are looping on your tokens (it appears that you are) then first time through the loop  `token` will be "array:", the second time it will be ".word" and the third time it will be "0:10".

This evaluation:

```
word_ptr = strstr(token, ".word")
```

will only find  ".word" during the iteration in which `token` contains ".word". When you then increment word_ptr by 6 chars you have moved past the end of `token` into undefined memory. Yes, "0:10" appears two characters after ".word" in your original string, but we are not looking at the original string in your call to `strstr`. We are looking just at `token` and `token` only contains ".word".

This is why it's failing. How to fix it depends somewhat on the rest of your implementation.

Comment: This is precisely what is happening. I didn't realize tokenizing will actually split the string into separate strings. Thank you so much. I need to find a way to grab the next token then.

Answer (score 2):

When you set `*string_wanted` to `word_ptr + 6`, you are pointing `string_wanted` at the `null` that terminates the string. So when you try to print `*string_wanted` you get an empty string. Try getting the next token instead.

Comment: Why does it point to `null`? Doesn't `word_ptr + 6` move it six spots to the right, and hence pointing to `0` of the `0:10` string?

Comment: I assume you are tokenizing on space, so `token` = `".word"`. Maybe you should add your tokenizing code.

Comment: Yea I am tokenizing on space too. But shouldn't incrementing the pointer still work?

Comment: If you are tokenizing on space then the entirety of `token` is ".word". Adding 6 to word_ptr will take you two bytes past the end of the token into memory that is not part of your string.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't your `if (strstr(token, ":"))` be true for all of your strings? It wouldn't ever get to the block of code you're asking about.

Comment: Oh please disregard that. It does actually get to my block of code I have a set of many conditions that I took out for simplicity for the readers. I just wanted to show that I have that in an if-else statement block.

Comment: You should probably update your question to the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate the error and also test that bare minimum yourself to verify that the problem still exists to ensure you aren't seeing side effects from code that we don't know about.